# Curvature and geodesic of $M = \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ with metric $ds^2 = dx^2 + ydy^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature, geodesic

> Let $M = \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ with the metric $ds^2 = dx^2 + ydy^2$
>
> > **a.** Calculate the Gaussian curvature of the abstract surface $M$
> >
> > **b.** Determine all geodesics in $M$ going through $(x_0, y_0)$ with tangent vector $(1, 0)$

**My attempt**

---

**a.** First we note that the matrix of the first fundamental form is $I =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & y \end{bmatrix}$.

From this, we determine that the only non-zero Christoffel symbol is $\Gamma_{vv}^v = \frac{1}{2v}$.

If we denote $R(x, y)z = \nabla_x\nabla_yz - \nabla_y\nabla_xz$, then the formula for the Gaussian curvature is $$K = \frac{\left< R(\mathbf{x}_u,\mathbf{x}_v)\mathbf{x}_v,\mathbf{x}_u\right>}{\left< \mathbf{x}_u,\mathbf{x}_u \right >\left< \mathbf{x}_v,\mathbf{x}_v \right > - \left< \mathbf{x}_u,\mathbf{x}_v \right >}$$

Now, using the formula for Gaussian curvature, we get that $$K = \frac{\left< \frac{-1}{2v^2}\mathbf{x}_v, \mathbf{x}_u\right>}{v}$$

---

**b.** We have that geodesics are the curves that satisfy $\nabla_{\alpha^\prime} \alpha^{\prime} = 0$

---

**The question**

First of all, is **a** correct? I think it is, but I may have been wrong in many places. Also, does $K$ simplify to $0$? It seems like it does, but I'm not too sure either...

Finally, how can I do **b**? I wrote down the equation, but I don't really know how to continue it. I think I should write $\alpha = \mathbf{x}(u(t), v(t))$, but I'm not very familiar with the context of abstract surfaces.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice $ds^2 = dx^2 + du^2$ where $u = \frac23 y^{3/2}$. Whatever you do to get the curvarture and geodesics, when you change variable to  $(x,u)$, the answer should become $0$ and straight lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint for part b**

(IMPORTANT: in the following context, direct superscripts on symbols do not imply raising to powers.)

The geodesics equations are
$$
\frac{\partial^2 x^i}{\partial s^2}+\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^i\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial s}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial s}=0,
$$
where $i,\alpha,\beta \in \{1,2\}$. In the case of your question, the geodesics are found among
$$
{\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial s^2}=0,
\\
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial s^2}+\frac{1}{2y}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial s})^2=0.
}
$$

**Additional Remark**

I couldn't fully conceive what $\Gamma_{vv}^v = \frac{1}{2v}$ means. Unless I'm missing something, the expression $\Gamma_{vv}^v = \frac{1}{2v}$ means
$$
{
\Gamma_{11}^1 = \frac{1}{2},
\\\Gamma_{22}^2 = \frac{1}{4},
}
$$
which is indeed incorrect. Actually, you should write the only non-zero Christoffel symbol as
$$
\Gamma_{22}^2 = \frac{1}{2x^2}=\frac{1}{2y}.
$$

Comment: For your additional comment: I guess OP uses the notations $(u,v)$ for the orthogonal directions diagonalizing the metric and identifies $u$ and $v$ with their respective index, that is why they wrote $\Gamma^v_{vv}= \frac{1}{2v}$. To be fair, I don't really like these notations since it is confusing

Comment: @Didier That’s exactly right. It’s the notation my DG professor used, and, since it’s not really my field of interest, I guess I just stuck with it…